# javascript prototype - find my issue

Tags: javascript, prototype

i written a simple javascript inheritance prototype, but i am getting issue.. any one guide me the correct declaration?

code:

```
var Man = function(params){
  this.name = params.name,
  this.age = params.age,
  this.job = params.job;
}

Man.prototype.work = function(){
  return this.name +' is working as a ' + this.job;
}

var Women = function(params){
  this.name = params.name,
  this.age = params.age,
  this.job = params.job;
}

Women.prototype = new Man(); //assigning the prototype

var man1 = new Man({name:'man1',age:'age1',job:'job1'});
console.log(man1.work()); //it works

var woman1 = new Women({name:'woman1',age:'age2',job:'job2'});
console.log(woman1.work()); // it is not.. why?
```

the error i am getting :

```
TypeError: params is undefined
[Break On This Error]   

this.name = params.name,
```

Comment: The woman doesn't want to work. Figures.

Comment: have you any errors in console?

Comment: What I always say: `Women.prototype = new Man();` is a bad way of of setting the prototype.

Comment: Don't use comma at the end. It is not as multiple `var` declaration.

Comment: @srigi: It does not make sense to use it, but it is not an issue.

Comment: Interesting to note that "JavaScript: The Definitive Guide" has a very similar example, except the equivalent `Man()` constructor accepts separate arguments rather than an object with properties. The separate arguments are simply `undefined` (so it "works"), whereas trying to access a property of an undefined object throws an Exception (so it does "not work").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not passing your parameters from the woman to the man, try this:

```
Women.prototype = new Man({name:this.name,age:this.age,job:this.job});
```

Actually, this would work also:

```
Women.prototype = new Man(this);
```

The advantage is that it's just 4 letters of extra code, and this *should* work on all browsers that support JS.

Comment: what is the need to pass the parameters 2 times?

Comment: `Work` is a function in the prototype of `Man`. It can't "see" the variables passed to `Women`, you'll have to pass it along.

Comment: This does not seem to be correct. What exactly is `this` in this context?

Comment: @FelixKling: it's `Women {name: "woman1", age: "age2", job: "job2"}`, in that case.

(I always test my code before posting ;-) )

Comment: So... where are you putting this line then? Because if it is were it is in the original code, `this` will refer to `window`... it might "work" but it is very unintuitive design.

Comment: Did you even test what you're claiming, @FelixKling? Replace the prototype in the example in the OP with this: `Women.prototype = function(){console.log(this)};` and see for yourself. `this` __definetly__ isn't `window`. If it were, there was no way `Women.prototype = new Man(this);` would work. Except it does work.

Comment: I guarantee you that `this` refers to `window`. The reason why you still get the correct output is because you are shadowing `name`, `age` and `job` through the `Women` constructor. The only reason it works is because you are passing an object to `Man`.  `Women.prototype = new Man({});` would work just as well. Have a look at the prototype chain: http://jsfiddle.net/QkjwB/1.

Comment: At the moment you are calling `Women.prototype = new Man(this);`, you did not even create a `Women` instance yet (you did not call `new Women` and passed any parameters to it). `this` cannot refer to the `Women` instance at this point.

Comment: @FelixKling: `new Man({});`? That's Bullsh... Wait... Darn, I stand corrected, that works. That's rather confusing o.O
My apologies for the harsh language, you're absolutely right.

Comment: @3gwebtrain: No offense, but this "solution" is merely a workaround. As soon as `Man` expects more than one argument, you potentially run into the same problem. And passing multiple *random* values to the function (because it almost does not matter what you pass) just makes the code more confusing. The real solution is *not calling* `Man` at that moment. Of course you can choose whatever works for you, just be aware of the problem.

Answer (score 4):

You are getting this error because you are calling `Man` without any arguments:

```
Women.prototype = new Man();
```

Since inside the function, `params` is `undefined`, accessing `params.name` will raise an exception.

That's one of the reasons why setting the prototype like this is inconvenient. You don't really want to create a new instance of `Man` at this moment, you only want to hook up its prototype into the prototype chain.

Better use [`Object.create` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) (includes polyfill) to create an object with a specific prototype:

```
Women.prototype = Object.create(Man.prototype);
Women.prototype.constructor = Women;
```

and inside `Women`, call the parent constructor (it's not meant to be a dirty joke) to pass along the arguments:

```
function Women(params) {
    Man.call(this, params);
}
```

Comment: Just to note browser support for the `create` method: **IE9+**, FF4+

Comment: @w3d: Added a link to the MDN documentation which has a polyfill.